# Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

when I want to go onclick  to next page's specific div it shows this error .

**jquery.js:3123 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame.**

and not going on specific div just on page.

**EDIT**

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 main-image"><img onclick="document.location='/discovers/styles-services#cat_eye';" src="pub/media/before-after/No/Back.jpg" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will likely be down to either trying to access an iFrame with Javascript, or you're trying to load an asset from a different server? I can't quite tell from your question sorry, it's not very clear.

> You can't access an `<iframe>` with Javascript, it would be a huge
>   security flaw if you could do it. For the same-origin policy browsers
>   block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin.
>
> Origin is considered different if at least one of the following parts
>   of the address isn't maintained:
>
> `<protocol>://<hostname>:<port>/path/to/page.html`  Protocol, hostname
>   and port must be the same of your domain, if you want to access a
>   frame.

Answer taken from [this stack exchange post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: If I am trying yo access a div by id  like    www.learner.com/new#accessdiv     still its not going to that div and give this error .

Comment: It sounds like it may be the URL you are using, is it on the same domain as the page you are on? If so try prepending `https://` to the URL or writing the path like this: `/new#accessdiv`.

Are you using an iframe at all?

Comment: can you see edited code ? I am doing like this

Comment: What happens if you change the location to `'https://your-url.com/discovers/styles-services#cat_eye'`?

Comment: just page refresh and navigate to where I left page.

Comment: Hmm the only idea I have left is to try `postMessage` workaround from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame).